# Missing HTML from C# Document Web browser

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a web page. For some reason, not all of the information that is being displayed on the page, can befound under DocumentText,OuterHTML, InnerHTML. The strange thing is that when I click on the JSON Visualizer (Data is not in Json Formatted), it shows the code. I have tried both with WebBrowser and HTTPWebRequest and I am getting the same results. When I create a breakpoint and check the value of documenttext in HTML mode it does show the missing information.

I used a sniffer for the webrequest and it detects one webrequest/response which returns all of the information (Including the missing portions).

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a way to access the missing information? Is there a way to reference the JSON visualizer data which display the missing data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what's going on. There are Ajax calls to get the content, I guess I have to execute them first...